# Finite rank operator with closed graph

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $X,Y$ normed vector spaces (non necessarily Banach). Suppose that $T:X\to Y$ is a linear operator such that his graph is closed and his rank has finite dimension. How I can prove that $T$ is continuous? If $X,Y$ are Banach the result is simply the closed graph theorem, but in the general how could I prove that?

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Suppose $T$ is not continuous. Then there exists a sequence  $(x_n)$ converging to $0$ such that $\|Tx_n\| \to \infty$.  Let $y_n=\frac {Tx_n} {\|Tx_n\|}$. Then $(y_n)$ is a bounded sequence in a finite dimesional space,  so it has  a convegent subsequence $(y_{n_k})$. Since $\|y_n\|=1$ for all $n$ it follows that $(y_{n_k})$ conveges to some $y$ of norm $1$. Now consider the sequence $(\frac {x_{n_k}} {\|Tx_n\|}, y_{n_k})$ in the graph of $T$. Can you finish?

Comment: X is not a finite dimensional space.

Comment: @math3341 There weer some typos. I have corrected the answer.

Comment: I have 2 questions with respect your hint. First, why can we take $(x_n)$ convergent? I understand that the fact that $T$ is not continuous implies that exists $(x_n)$ bounded such that $\|Tx_n\|\to\infty$, but i don´t know why $(x_n)$ can be convergent. Second, can you explain to me what converges $x_{n_k}/\|Tx_n\|$ ? Thanks.

Comment: @math3341 If $(u_n)$ is bounded and $\|Tu_n\|\to \infty$ then $x_n=\frac {u_n} {\sqrt {\|Tu_n\|}} \to 0$ and $\|Tx_n\| \to \infty$. (This is a very standard argument used in almost any book on FA, so I did spell out the details). The limit of $x_{n_k}/\|Tx_{n_k}\|$ is $0$ since the denominator tends to $\infty$.

Comment: But $x_{n_k}$ tends to $0$ too, so necessarily $x_{n_k}/\|Tx_n\|\to0$? And $y_{n_k}\to0$?

Comment: $\|y_n\|=1$ by definition of $y_n$. For this reason $y_{n_k}$ cannot tend to $0$. It tends to some vector of norm $1$. @math3341